# ImportError: DLL load failed: %1 is not a valid Win32 application pywin32

Tags: python, pywin32, win32gui

I am trying to imort the pywin32 library, but I am getting an error.

```
import win32api
ImportError: DLL load failed: %1 is not a valid Win32 application.
```

or

```
import win32gui 
ImportError: DLL load failed: %1 is not a valid Win32 application.
```

Does anybody know what the problem might be?

Comment: I don't think this question is duplicated, since win32api is used in many other packages. Anyways, just in case someone stumbles upon this, after October 2019: 
 1. you need have pywin32 installed.  2. use **pywin version 224**, since versions after October 2019 are broken

Answer (score 0):

The bitness of the packages you have installed differs; make sure all of the programs/libraries have the same bitness.

- If you are running a 32-bit version of Windows, make sure you have the 32-bit version of Python and the 32-bit version of PyWin32
- If you are running a 64-bit version of Windows, make sure you have the 64-bit version of Python and the 64-bit version of PyWin32